# List<Vector3>, how get an item from it?

Tags: c#, xna

I have such code:

```
List<Vector3> list = fillTheList();
```

How can I get element from it on specyfied position?

Comment: `Vector3 element = list[position]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it by using its indexer.

```
var item = list[index];
```

Lists also have indexers like arrays do.

Comment: you're welcome, though googling a bit would have helped to you know.

Answer (score 3):

For example if you want to have the second item in the list you would write:

```
var vectorFromList = list[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`List` has an indexer that accepts `integer`, the index of the element in the List

```
ls[0]  // gets the first element
ls[1]  // gets the second element
```